# Convert GDI Plus Bitmap to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, gdi+, qimage, qpixmap

I have a GdiPlus::Bitmap object, and I need to build a function that converts it to a QPixmap.  I'm using Qt 5.8.0, and performance is a concern of mine.  I cannot find anything about this online, even searching for GDI+ images to QImages.  I don't NEED to access pixel data, so all I have to do is get a GDI+ bitmap converted into something that can be displayed in a QWidget.

The most promising solution I've found so far is to use the fromHBitMap() in QtWin: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwin.html#fromHBITMAP, but I don't have the required knowledge/experience to be able to understand handles to bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have "Bitmap" object in your hand. 
Also I assume your development environment supports both "Windows programming" and "Qt".

Based on above assumptions, you can get the `HICON` from the "Bitmap" and pass it to "`QPixmap QtWin::fromHICON(HICON icon`)".

Steps:

First you have to include "`Gdiplus.h`".
Also include "`QtWin`".

```
HICON hIcon;
Status st = <<Your Bitmap Object>>.GetHICON(&hIcon);
QPixmap pixM = QtWin::fromHICON(hIcon);
```

Try this. 
The above code is untested. 
It gives an idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't NEED to access pixel data

You don't, but Qt most certainly does. Qt does not use GDI for rendering widgets - instead, it uses the raster backend that operates on a `QImage`. Under the hood a `QPixmap` is just a wrapper around a `QImage` and it's cheap to convert between the two as it doesn't copy any image data.

So, whatever route you choose will involve `QImage` at some point, even if it's in the form of a `QPixmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a method of doing this where I flipped the red and blue bytes, then used the following code to convert it from a Gdiplus::Bitmap to a QPixmap:

```
QPixmap getAsQPixmap(Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap)
{
   // One of my functions to flip blue and red bytes of the image
   _flipBlueWithRed();

   // m_pBytes is a pointer to an unsigned char that marks the start of the image
   // It was retrieved from locking the Gdiplus::Bitmap
   auto result = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(m_pBytes, getWidth(), getHeight(), QImage::Format_RGB888));

   // Restore data back to original state
   _flipBlueWithRed();

   return result;
}
```

This method, however, was slow and took a good 60 milliseconds to execute.  So my new method was to save the Gdiplus::Bitmap to file, and use the path to that file to read in from QPixmap's constructor.  **This method is MUCH faster, around 5 milliseconds.**

```
QPixmap getAsQPixmap(GdiPlus::Bitmap bitmap)
{
    std::string path = "C:/path_to_img.....png";

    // One of my functions to unlock the Gdi+ bitmap
    _unlockGdiPlusBitmap();

    // Get Clsid
    CLSID pngClsid;
    getEncoderClsid(format_mime, &pngClsid);

    // Save bitmap
    // stringToWString() was a function that I wrote to convert a standard string to be a wide string
    bitmap->Save(stringToWString(path).c_str(), static_cast<const CLSID*>(&pngClsid));

    // Lock bitmap
    _lockGdiPlusBitmap();

    // Create the QPixmap
    QPixmap new_img(path);

    return new_img;
}
```